# Changing oneside and twoside layout

Tags: margins, geometry, double-sided

Is there any solution to use different layouts according to the `oneside` or `twoside` specification?

The first part of my report (abstract, ToC, LoF, LoT) should be in `oneside` mode
and the rest of the document should be in `twoside` mode.

P.S. I'm using the `geometry` package for setting the layout:

```
\usepackage[twoside,width=16cm,height=24cm,left=3cm]{geometry}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm not sure *why* you want to switch from `oneside` to `twoside` mid-document, and a textblock of 16 cm width and 24 cm height won't look pretty. That said, it *is* possible to change most `geometry` settings mid-document since version 5.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]

\newgeometry{twoside}

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, that  solve my problem changing oneside to twoside layout.

Comment: @Anja: You're welcome -- and upvoting and accepting my answer would also be nice. :-)

Comment: Have you any suggestions about width and height of text to look as standard word document (stupid faculty policy)

Comment: @Anja: If you *have to* use a textblock of 16*24cm, switch to a basic fontsize of 11pt or 12pt and choose a "broad" font like Palatino (`\usepackage{mathpazo}`).

Comment: Thanks again. The package `mathpazo` provides really  nice layout.

Comment: Should `\newgeometry{oneside}` work?

Answer (score 4):

As long as you can be pretty sure that the frontmatter pages (titlepage, toc, lof, lot, abstract) only take up one page, you need do very little to make them show up on the recto (odd-numbered, right-hand) pages of the document: in all instances when you'd issue a `\clearpage` command -- or where LaTeX would do this implicitly, e.g., when it encounters a command such as `\listoftables` -- you need to issue an explicit `\cleardoublepage` command.

The following MWE illustrates how this works. You didn't mention which document class you're using, so I'm assuming it's `report`. (The MWE will work with the `article` class as well, but you'll have to replace `\chapter` with `\section`.) By the way, if you state the option `twoside` in the `\documentclass` command, it'll be passed on automatically to all packages, including `geometry`, that are loaded later on. Remember to run LaTeX on it twice in order to generate the table of contents, etc.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage[width=16cm,height=24cm,left=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum,tocbibind}   
\begin{document}
%% Use roman page numbering in frontmatter
\pagenumbering{roman}
\author{Me}
\title{Some thoughts}
\date{\today}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}

\cleardoublepage
\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage
\listoffigures

\cleardoublepage
\listoftables

\cleardoublepage
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\cleardoublepage
%% In main body of paper, use arabic page numbers
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Where Are We Going?}

\lipsum[2] 

\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{Random Stuff}
\centering
xyz
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Utterly Random}
\centering
abc
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but my table of contents has several pages (also toc and tof). I'm using book class...

Comment: I see that "lockstep" has provided a good answer in the meantime. :-)