# Change twoside to oneside mid-document

Tags: double-sided

Title says it all, i've found answers to changing oneside to twoside but the other way around won't work.
So is this possible? And if so, how?

Comment: Could you provide the community with something to start with, like a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)? Switching such structural components mid-document may be depending on your existing usage of packages or a specific class. So it would be helpful to know this. Also, you mention that you "found answers" doing the opposite. How about pointing the community to those via links so there's at least some reference...?

Comment: Relevant: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28359/8666

Answer (score 3):

Possible, but it might be more clean to use two different documents and use package `pdfpages` to merge them. Just look at the warning generated by package `typearea` ;-)

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\cleardoublepage
\KOMAoption{twoside}{false}
%\recalctypearea% <-  the recalculation is done by default
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\KOMAoption{twoide}{false}` starts automatically a recalculation of the page layout using `\recalctypearea`. So you could remove the explicit  `\recalctypearea` - or the calculation is done twice (see the log file) and you get the warning twice.

Comment: @esdd Ah, i didn't really pay attention. It shouldn't  have a great influence on compiling time and better save then sorry, but i'll comment out that bit. Once more, thanks for dropping a note. I am glad to see a KOMA expert floating around here :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{title}
\lipsum
\chapter{title}
\lipsum
\makeatletter\@twosidefalse\@mparswitchfalse\makeatother
\lipsum
\chapter{title}
\lipsum
\chapter{title}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```