# How to set two-sided margin for elsarticle?

Tags: pdftex, double-sided, elsarticle

Could you please tell me how I can set two-sided margin of my latex file if the document class is a **elsarticle**? I tried many packages, e.g. \oddsidemargin, \evensidemargin, \geometry, etc. But none of these worked.

I used `\documentclass[12pt,3p,times,twoside]{elsarticle}`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Load geometry and use the command

```
\usepackage{geometry}

\newgeometry{twoside}
```

where you want twosided geometry to begin.

According to the documentation, the `elsarticle` class allows for all the same options as the `article` class. However, the `twoside` option, whether as a global option for `\documentclass` or as an option in `geometry`, did nothing.

I found using the command  after loading the `geometry` package worked. I tried this after seeing it used here: [Changing oneside and twoside layout](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28359/changing-oneside-and-twoside-layout).